# How to import from csv or excel file to RDS for SQL Server by Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, amazon-rds

We're developing Excel VBA tool to import excel data to RDS for SQL Server. First I tried to export excel data to csv on local PC and then bulk insert it to RDS SQL Server, but it couldn't, since RDS can't access my local PC, not like SQL Server on Windows Server.

I understand current RDS for SQL Server accepts bulk insert from S3.
But our users are in Financial division and can't use S3 nor the special utilities like bcp. So now I try to create insert query by Excel VBA and execute it by ADO or ODBC.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: how did you solve the issue?

Comment: Readers would need a [mcve] to help with this question. Closing for now.

Comment: @Mik Sorry for my late reply. I hate to tell you this but we created the insert or update query by VBA since it was not huge data at that time. Not smart way, we know. Hopefully you would find better solutions.